# Angular ui-grid header chopped

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This is what I got:
[image]

While menu button is a bit taller than normal, header is chopped into half.

HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .TreeCCS {width: 900px; height: 250px;}
    </style>
<div ng-controller="ctrlMyTree">
            <br />ANGULAR
            <div id="afad" ui-grid="grdMyTree" ui-grid-tree-view class="TreeCCS">
            </div>
        </div>
```

.js:

```
var aIS = angular.module("app", ["ui.grid", "ui.grid.treeView"]);
aIS.controller("ctrlMyTree", function ($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.grdMyTree= { enableGridMenu: true, showTreeExpandNoChildren: true, enableTreeView: true, };
```

Node and leaf levels are not defined yet, following [this official tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/215_treeView) but using dynamic json to load data. Works if Take out all tree-related.

ui.grid.js = 3.2.9. What am I missing here?

Comment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZI7y6cCBW4l5z2oV4xX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is showTreeExpandNoChildren, should be false rather than true(default). Although not documented,

> showTreeExpandNoChildren: defaults to true. Shows the + sign even if
>   there are no children, allows you to dynamically load children. If set
>   to false there'll be no + if there are no children.

[Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3663),